# Why can't I mock a function inside jest.Mock (have to use .mockImplementation on spyOn)?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I expected that when I mocked a module using `jest.mock()` and passed function implementations to each object, they would carry over to the tests.

```
import * as services from '_services';

// I thought this would be enough to mock 'load_basket'
jest.mock('_services', () => ({
  load_basket: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([]))
}));

describe('WB Component', () => {
  it('loads basket if basket prop is null', () => {

    // However, if I don't use .mockImplemenation here it gives
    // me an error that load_basket wasn't called
    const spy = spyOn(services, 'load_basket').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([]));
    const wrapper = shallow(<WB basket={null} />);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    wrapper.unmount();
    spy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

But I can remove the function implementation in `.mock` and have just `load_basket: jest.fn()`, but I can't remove the `.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([]))` at the bottom or I'll get `expected spy to have been called, but it was not called`.

Edit: If i have neither the function implementation in the original `.mock` call or the `.mockImplementation`, it'll give me a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`...load_basket being the 'undefined'. That sort of makes sense to me, but I still don't understand why mocking the function in `.mock` makes it a different function from the spied one inside the test?

Edit2: `load_basket` is used in the following way

```
class WB extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      basket: props.basket,
      loading_basket: !props.basket,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(): void {
    if (!this.state.basket) {
      load_basket()
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({
            basket: res,
            loading_basket: false
          });
        })
        .catch( ... );
    }
  }

  render () { ... }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how `load_basket` is being used in your `WB` component?  (I'm guessing it is called as the response to a resolved `Promise` but I just want to make sure)

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors Added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) accepts an optional `factory` parameter and if one is provided then the `module` is replaced with the result of calling the `factory` parameter.

So `services.load_basket` is *already* a [mock function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api) by the time your test function gets called.

---

**Error Details**

You are calling `spyOn` which ends up calling the [undocumented legacy `Jasmine` `spyOn` function](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/c15b7a5701e55d751bcd3c93eceef7dab271f4ff/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine/jasmineLight.js#L139-L141) (`Jest` is based on `Jasmine`), I'm guessing you meant to call [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname).

The `spyOn` function from `Jasmine` doesn't work correctly with the `Jest` mock function, which ends up causing the error you are seeing if you don't also mock the implementation.

Note that if you had called `jest.spyOn` it would just [return the existing mock function](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/c15b7a5701e55d751bcd3c93eceef7dab271f4ff/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L999-L1023) since `load_basket` is already a mock function, and it would have worked without a mock implementation.

---

With all that said, you don't need to spy on `services.load_basket` since *it is already a mock function*.

Your test can be simplified to this:

```js
import * as services from '_services';

jest.mock('_services', () => ({
  load_basket: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([]))
}));

describe('WB Component', () => {
  it('loads basket if basket prop is null', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<WB basket={null} />);
    expect(services.load_basket).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow, the calling of undocumented legacy code seems like really broken behavior.

Comment: Guess they don't expect people to stumble on it, but yeah it should probably emit a warning

Comment: @NilsGuillermin  If you need help verifying the `state` was set properly in the `Promise` callback within `componentDidMount` then open a new question and tag me, doing that is a little tricky